# How to disallow past dates using the datepicker in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I know we can add validation preventing past dates from being chosen by running javascript on the fields OnChange event.  However is it possible to disable past dates within the datepicker? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported and documented way of doing it. So the only way is usage of OnChange event handler.

Comment: What about unsupported ways ? Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Manipulations with DOM but I would not recommend this way.